# Dynamically change points of a gradient brush?

Tags: c#

I think you all know this little friend:

```
new LinearGradientBrush(PointF, PointF, Color, Color)
```

I need to change these points multiply times per second and I am not sure how. I thought about creating the object multiple times would do but that was a mistake since my program crashes due to memory problems.

I need a way to update the gradient brush points, is there any way to do this?

Comment: I am not familiar with this friend. I guess it is not from `System.Windows.Media` [package](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush(v=vs.110).aspx), right? Because it has constructor when the `Point`s are the last (and also has setters for the `Point`s) so which package are you using?

Comment: @KernelMode System.Drawing.Drawing2D

Comment: `LinearGradientBrush` is a `Freezable`, so I doubt you'll be able to modify it after being first applied. Is the points change cyclic or are there really new points each time?

Comment: @grek40 I just need to change the value of the points on each cycle if that answers your question.

Comment: Before I continue thinking about it, please explain what you actually want to archieve. Sometimes a bit of `LayoutTransform` and `RenderTransform` can do wonderful things to the visual appearance of an unchanged brush. Got the feeling we're having a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly! - Maybe you can create a set on brushes? LinearGradientBrush.Rectangle is read-only.